# How to spawn ghostcript into node.js environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, ghostscript, spawn

I have tried different configuration, but I cannot seem to succeed to execute "gs" (Ghostscript) in a node.js environment.

```
var fs = require( "fs" ),
      child_process = require( 'child_process' );
```

...

```
    var spawn = child_process.spawn;
    var opts = [
        "-q ",
        "-dQUIET ",
        "-dSAFER ",
        "-dBATCH ",
        "-dNOPAUSE ",
        "-dNOPROMPT ",
        "-dMaxBitmap=500000000 ",
        "-dAlignToPixels=0 ",
        "-dGridFitTT=2 ",
        "-sDEVICE=jpeg ",
        "-dTextAlphaBits=4 ",
        "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 ",
        "-r150 ",
        "-sOutputFile=afile.jpg",
        " afile.pdf"
    ];

    var gs = spawn( "gs", opts, { cwd: "/mnt/drive/" } );
    gs.stdout.on( 'data', function( data ) {
        console.log( 'stdout: ' + data );
    } );

    gs.stderr.on( 'data', function( data ) {
        console.log( 'stderr: ' + data );
    } );

    gs.on( 'close', function( code ) {
        console.log( 'child process exited with code ' + code );
    } );
```

**---Output ---------------------------------------------------------**

```
stdout: Unknown device: jpeg 

stdout: Unrecoverable error: undefined
stdout:  in .uninstallpagedevice

stdout: Operand stack:
    defaultdevice
stdout: 

child process exited with code 1
```

**-------------------------------------------------------------------**

The `/mnt/drive` directory is +read+write for all users.  The `gs -help` execution returns:

```
root@Machine:/# gs -help
GPL Ghostscript 9.05 (2012-02-08)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
Usage: gs [switches] [file1.ps file2.ps ...]
Most frequently used switches: (you can use # in place of =)
 -dNOPAUSE           no pause after page   | -q       `quiet', fewer messages
 -g<width>x<height>  page size in pixels   | -r<res>  pixels/inch resolution
 -sDEVICE=<devname>  select device         | -dBATCH  exit after last file
 -sOutputFile=<file> select output file: - for stdout, |command for pipe,
                                         embed %d or %ld for page #
Input formats: PostScript PostScriptLevel1 PostScriptLevel2 PostScriptLevel3 PDF
Default output device: bbox
Available devices:
   ...
   ijs imagen inferno inkcov iwhi iwlo iwlq jetp3852 jj100 jpeg jpegcmyk
   jpeggray la50 la70 la75 la75plus laserjet lbp310 lbp320 lbp8 lex2050
   ...
   txtwrite uniprint xcf xes
Search path:
   /usr/share/ghostscript/9.05/Resource/Init :
   /usr/share/ghostscript/9.05/lib :
   /usr/share/ghostscript/9.05/Resource/Font :
   /usr/share/ghostscript/fonts : /var/lib/ghostscript/fonts :
   /usr/share/cups/fonts : /usr/share/ghostscript/fonts :
   /usr/local/lib/ghostscript/fonts : /usr/share/fonts
For more information, see /usr/share/doc/ghostscript/Use.htm.
Please report bugs to bugs.ghostscript.com.
root@Machine:/#
```

Where the device **jpeg** is available.  The `gs` execution is not perform.  Any hint would be help ?

Comment: Stupid question: what happens if you run the exact same cmd on the cmd line? `Unknown device: jpeg` seems like a gs error (to `stdout` though?)..

Comment: Not stupid, I did not comment on that test, but yes, it does work with this command on the linux line.

Comment: For information, I changed the `-sOutputFile=afile.jpg` for a png extension, and the `-sDEVICE=png256` without luck. Same "Unknown device".

Comment: Maybe node runs child processes as a different user or chroot or sandbox? I honestly don't know. Maybe the ghostscript people know. Does it work in a cronjob etc?

Comment: @Rudie, the node.js code is started with the same user as the user id used to test the successful raw command on the shell command.

Comment: I tried your exact script (different filename and `cwd`) and it works perfectly for me. Including the quiet. Only output is the "child process exited with code 0". Can you try with a different or no `cwd`?

Comment: The only way I got it to work, is by upgrading node from 10.26 to the latest 10.32, AND encapsulate the gs execution in a simple bash script file.  Otherwise, even with the 10.32 node version, I still get the same error.  I suspected an environment problem like suggest @Rudie, however, I copied the entire integral directory to a subdirectory below this node script, without any success.  Same error.  Should I display other versions and environment extract ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I got it to work, is by upgrading node from 10.26 to the latest 10.32, AND encapsulate the gs execution in a simple bash script file. Otherwise, even with the 10.32 node version, I still get the same error. I suspected an environment problem like suggest @Rudie,

Answer (score 0):

You could consider to use Ghostscript4JS, it's a module that binds the Ghostscript C command API to bring its power to the Node.JS world.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ghostscript4js

Ghostscript4JS is a native Node.JS addon so you can call the C command Ghostscript API directly from your JavaScript code. In this way you have two benefits:

1. Better error handling:
   You directly intercept the error through the try/catch for the sync method and then/catch promise for the async method.
2. Performance
   The call to the shell command takes more time and more resources than the     call to the C or C++ API directly from Node.js environment.

As programmer you have more control against call external tool.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the spaces in the list of options

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).